# EntityState.Added has no effect in a particular case

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity

Since yesterday I have been stuck on an issue regarding an entity which not seems to be added after `SaveChanges()` in a particular case.

I have a table `Person`, and a table `History` which has a foreign key `PersonId`.
Thus, my Person entities have a `Histories` property generated by EF which is an ICollection of `History`.

I guess the problem may be simple, but I just can't figure it out...

Here is my page :

```
public partial class MyPage
{
    private MyService service;
    private Person person;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        service = new MyService();
        person = service.GetCurrentPerson(Request.QueryString["id"]);
    }

    protected void _SomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Discipline.TypeE disc = something;
        service.Test(equine, disc);
    }
}
```

And here is my service :

```
public class MyService
{
    private HistoryRepo historyRepo = new HistoryRepo();
    private PersonRepo personRepo = new PersonRepo();

    public Person GetCurrentPerson(string id)
    {
        //Returns the current person from the given id
    }

    public void Test(Person person, Discipline.LabelE disc)
    {
        using (var uof = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            historyRepo.AddOrUpdate(new History(person, History.ActionE.Competition));
            personRepo.AddOrUpdate(person);
            uof.Commit(); // just does a SaveChanges()

            int historiesCount = person.Histories.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

This works, and `historiesCount` is incremented.
However, if I just add this line this doesn't work anymore :

```
    public void Test(Person person, Discipline.LabelE disc)
    {
        using (var uof = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            List<Person> someVariableINeed = personRepo.GetByCompetition(disc); // this line

            historyRepo.AddOrUpdate(new History(person, History.ActionE.Competition));
            personRepo.AddOrUpdate(person);
            uof.Commit();

            int historiesCount = person.Histories.Count;
        }
    }
```

`someVariableINeed` is not even used but yet, `person.Histories` is not incremented anymore.
If I refresh the page it is, but right after the uof.Commit() it is not, and I need it right here...

I checked and in both cases, `AddOrUpdate` just does this : `entry.State = EntityState.Added;`

I don't think that `personRepo.GetByCompetition` may be the problem itself since replacing it by `Person someOtherVariable = personRepo.Get(person.Id);` (for example) does not make it work better.

However, it works with another example like `List<Competition> someOtherVariable = inscriptionRepo.GetByDiscipline(disc);`.

I really don't know where the problem is.
If anyone has an idea please feel free, I can add additional code if you need.

Thanks a lot.

***EDIT***

The repositories :

```
public class PersonRepo : RepositoryBase<Person>
{
    public List<Person> GetByCompetition(Discipline.TypeE disc)
    {
        var result =
            from person in entities.Persons
            join comp in entities.Competitions
            on new { ident = person.Id, discipline = (int)disc } equals new { ident = comp.PersonId, discipline = comp.DisciplineId } into tuple
            select person;

        return result.ToList();
    }
}

public class RepositoryBase<TObject> where TObject : class, IEntity
{
    protected Entities entities
    {
        get { return UnitOfWork.Current.Context; }
    }
}

public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private const string _httpContextKey = "_unitOfWork";
    private Entities _dbContext;

    public static UnitOfWork Current
    {
        get { return (UnitOfWork)HttpContext.Current.Items[_httpContextKey]; }
    }

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Items[_httpContextKey] = this;
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. The Unit Of Work and the Repositories need share the same instance of a `DbContext`

Comment: 2. `entry.State = EntityState.Added` will add the entire hierarchy: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply Colin, I edited the first post with the repositories code. In theory they do share the same instance of context ;)